# Typical .gitignore file for an Android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, gitignore

Just put an Android project under git (*beanstalk*) version control via the command line (*mac terminal*). Next step is to set up exclusions.

To those of you who have already been down this path:

**What should a typical .gitignore file look like for an android project?**

*Project set up in Eclipse*

Answer (score 180, accepted):

You can mix [Android.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore):

```
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties
```

with [Eclipse.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Eclipse.gitignore):

```
*.pydevproject
.project
.metadata
bin/**
tmp/**
tmp/**/*
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.classpath
.settings/
.loadpath

# External tool builders
.externalToolBuilders/

# Locally stored "Eclipse launch configurations"
*.launch

# CDT-specific
.cproject

# PDT-specific
.buildpath
```

Comment: I didn't know github's gitignore repository, that's really an useful hint, thanks.

Comment: Do you *really* want to ignore .classpath?  That seems a rather important thing to have in your git repository.

Comment: Interestingly, it looks like that's been altered since your comment, Chris.  Thanks for the heads up!  The updated file is in the link he posted.

Comment: In addition to .classpath, the other file you _don't_ want to ignore is .project.

Answer (score 16):

In addition to what the others have suggested, I'd like to add the `proguard` folder, in case you are using it. You can either ignore the whole folder or just `dump.txt`, `seeds.txt` and `usage.txt`. Basically, it's a good idea to keep `mapping.txt` versioned, so that you can debug obfuscated stack traces from your users. More details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html#considerations).

Answer (score 5):

This is my standard Android `.gitignore` and `.hgignore` file. It usually works pretty well.

```
bin
gen
target
.settings
.classpath
.project
*.keystore
*.swp
*.orig
*.log
*.properties
seed.txt
map.txt
```

It has eclipse, vim .swp files, mavens target folder and files for proguard mapping included.

Update: I have put my [.gitignore for Android development online](https://gist.github.com/keyboardsurfer/3240022).

Comment: Why the keystore file is there?

Comment: To not commit it, in case it's in that folder.

Comment: Yes but why? ``

Answer (score 4):

Well I know that the github/gitignore repository on GitHub has an [android .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore) file. This might be what you want as it should be very general for android development.

The actual content of the mentioned file:

```
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the one I use in my Android projects, it supports both ADT and Android Studio, so it is good if you are working with a team.

```
# General Folders

# gradle/ comment this when using gradle wrapper.
build/
bin/
gen/
tmp/
# proguard/ comment if not using proguard.
.gradle/
.settings/
.idea/

# General Files

.project
.classpath
.DS_Store
local.properties
*.iml
# gradlew comment when using gradle wrapper
# gradlew.bat comment when using gradle wrapper
Thumbs.db


# files specific to current project
your_apk.apk
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply [github](https://github.com/) can generate `.gitignore` for Android projects repositories

[image]

And its content will be like the following

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the ART/Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/
out/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Android Studio Navigation editor temp files
.navigation/

# Android Studio captures folder
captures/

# IntelliJ
*.iml
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/assetWizardSettings.xml
.idea/dictionaries
.idea/libraries
.idea/caches

# Keystore files
# Uncomment the following line if you do not want to check your keystore files in.
#*.jks

# External native build folder generated in Android Studio 2.2 and later
.externalNativeBuild

# Google Services (e.g. APIs or Firebase)
google-services.json

# Freeline
freeline.py
freeline/
freeline_project_description.json

# fastlane
fastlane/report.xml
fastlane/Preview.html
fastlane/screenshots
fastlane/test_output
fastlane/readme.md
```

Answer (score 0):

In Addition, if you use IDEA's IntelliJ, and you build *Artifacts* (and you should), then you might want to add:

```
out/
```

(that's where Artifacts are built by default).

And if you don't want to share your IntelliJ project stuff ignore

```
.idea/
```

Answer (score -1):

In my project root I have a file .gitignore. It contains:

```
/bin/
/gen/
```