# Can the bin folder in Android be ignored from version control?

Tags: android, git, version-control

Is it necessary for the bin folder to be synced when making an Android application?

They would automatically be regenerated anyway when the source is compiled right?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476376/typical-gitignore-file-for-an-android-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the thumb of rule seems to be that nothing that is automatically generated should be checked into to your version control system.

This includes binaries (/bin) as well as the build folder (e.g. /target) in case you use Maven or any other build system.

*(Just FYI, it is common practice that even libraries such as Log4j are **not** checked into your VCS as your build system should take charge of downloading these files for you. In this regard, even IDE configuration files shouldn't be checked in as they can normally be generated by your build system. E.g. using: mvn eclipse:eclipse)*

Answer (score 1):

It is always advisable to not dump anything and everything on version control. Just keep the files, folders which are necessary to you or other developer who is going to use it. Even .settings or .metadata, bin, gen etc. In Tortoise SVN you can select the folder(s) you want to add to ignore list right click Select TortoiseSVN > add to ignore list > by name or what ever option you like to select. And don't forget to commit this Folder (FolderName - svn:ignore list) to SVN.