# Android Studio .gitignore location

Tags: android-studio, gitignore

I have a project that I recently added to Git and I can't seem to locate my .gitignore file. Anyone know where it should be? And if it's missing, how to get it back?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476376/typical-gitignore-file-for-an-android-app?rq=1) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744305/how-to-create-gitignore-file?rq=1) might help.

Comment: Thanks legoscia, found my answer by digging in the second link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If files are ignored, but you don't find any .gitignore, then those ignore rules can by in other spots specific by [`gitignore` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

- `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`
- file specified by the configuration variable '`core.excludesfile`'.

If you think a file is ignore, but you don't know by which ignore file, you can type:

```
git check-ignore -v yourFile
```

Comment: Is `check-ignore` an alias? I get `git: 'check-ignore' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: @MiserableVariable you need git 1.8.3.3+ (preferably 1.8.5+) for git check-ignore (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore)

Comment: Thanks. My cygwin64 git is at 1.7.9 so I guess I got to wait a little bit.

Comment: @MiserableVariable ok, but why use cygwin at all for Git? Msysgit works just fine: https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/. http://stackoverflow.com/a/784743/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3144417/6309

Comment: Because I have been using cygwin for a long time :) the rest of msys is very old

Comment: @MiserableVariable regarding git, it has been a few years that Cygwin is no longer useful. And Gow is recent enough: https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I know about cygwin limitations but after 20 years using cygwin and 25 years using emacs I don't know if I can handle the learning curve -- those backslashes are slippery :)

Comment: Thanks to this discussion I found http://sourceware.org/cygwinports/ and now I am 1.8.5.5. Thank you!

Comment: @MiserableVariable Great! That should improve the situation.