# Resolve Conflicts Between Two Branches

Tags: android, git, bitbucket

I'm working on an application and managing its repo on bitbucket.

During the development process, I created a new branch 'price-module' a few days ago and pushed its changes in the remote branch by the same name. Now, when I'm merging 'price-module' to 'master' branch, bitbucket is showing me an error that there are conflicts between some files. (specifically in bin/R.txt). How can I resolve these conflicts and merge the changes I did in 'price-module' to 'master' branch without losing my code?

PS: the project I'm working on is an Android project.

**Update: what have I tried so far to solve the problem**

I did some research on my own to try and solve the conflict between files. These are the steps I took to solve the conflict:

- Switched to master branch, manually overridden the conflicted files by copying them from 'price-module' branch (they are mainly `gen` or `bin`), pushed them to master and then tried to merge 'price-module' into 'master' -- FAILED!
- Added Android-specific rules in `exclude` file in my `.git` folder from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8476584/1303004) but the `gen` and `bin` folders kept showing up.

Comment: For conflict resolution you can use Kdiff3

Answer (score 1):

In an Android project, you should not be storing the `bin` folder in version control in the first place as it contains only generated files. Though `R.txt` isn't one of them, there's `R.java` in `gen/your/package/name`.

Assuming it's the generated `bin` folder, you should remove it from git, add it to `.gitignore` so it doesn't show up as non-versioned in git status, merge or re-apply the deletion to both branches, and just let the build tools generate `bin` files as needed.

For more things to not put in version control, see [Typical .gitignore file for an Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476376/typical-gitignore-file-for-an-android-app)

Comment: So I add `bin` to `.gitignore`, checkout the 'development' branch, delete `bin` folder, push it on bitbucket. Do the same for 'price-module' and then merge 'price-module' in 'development', yes?