# eclipse eGit - what file types to commit?

Tags: android, eclipse, git, egit, git-commit

I am working on an android app in eclipse ADT and just started to use eGit (git plugin).

I set up my repository outside of the workspace - and I am about to do my first commit.

Now, when I do the commit there is a dialog to choose what files do I want to commit.

**My question is:** what file types I **should** commit and what file types I **shouldn't** commit **(in an android app project)** and why?

I did see in many tutorials that sometimes they commit only code file (.java) and other files they don't necessarily.

So (for android app) what files should I commit?

Comment: check this out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476376/typical-gitignore-file-for-an-android-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should commit any source file that will help build (or test) your application, such as `.java` source files of `.xml` layout files. Any file that can be generated by the other files (e.g., `.class` compiled classes) should not be committed.

Comment: thanks for your answer. so, basically, only .java and .xml files? meaning all code, all layout and manifest. what about the drawables resources? and .class files?

Comment: resources should be committed. `.class` files should definitely not be - they can always be compiled from source, so there's no reason to save them.

Comment: so files of type: .java, .xml and resource files. got it, thanks!

Comment: one more question - I have android-support-v4.jar in my libs folder, and also using the google_play_services and android-support-v7-appcompat libraries as libraries in my project properties. should I commit any of those stuff?

Comment: @OfekAgmon there's no reason to commit external libraries. Your build environment (gradle presumably?) should know how to pull them.